# How to access Square connect error "detail" with PHP?

Tags: php, square-connect

I am trying to retrieve the `detail` of a Square API Error object using the PHP SDK.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$err = $e->getResponseBody()->errors['0']->detail;
```

This works, but is there a better way to return error message(s)? I have read [error related info](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#handlingerrors) in the documentation but was unable to find any code to get the `detail` property with PHP.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you might want to use [`getDetail()`](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Model/Error.md) instead of `->detail`